# Best way to query XML in C# - using LINQ, etc

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml message that I need to parse (No control of format) that looks something like the below (Name / Value Pairs) that I need to process.  What would be the best method for querying the values out where Name = x and Get the related Value?

I am currently using a nested select to try and get the value out of a specific Name / Value pair.  Just wondering if an easier LINQ / Lambda call I could use instead.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<Message>
<MessageContent>
  <MessageDetails>
    <Name>System_ID</Name>
    <Value>12345</Value>
  </MessageDetails>
  <MessageDetails>
    <Name>System_Name</Name>
    <Value>Test System</Value>
  </MessageDetails>
</MessageContent>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Linq to XML:

```
var xml = XElement.Load(someXmlFile);
var results = xml.Descendants("MessageDetails")
                 .Where(m => m.Element("Name").Value == someValue)
                 .Select(m => m.Element("Value").Value);
```

If you expect only one match add a `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first matching value.

Judging by your xml it looks like you could also benefit from projecting to a dictionary (if your `Name` element values are unique):

```
var dictionary = xml.Descendants("MessageDetails")
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Element("Name").Value, 
                                  x => x.Element("Value").Value);
```

Now you can just use the dictionary:

```
string value = dictionary["System_ID"];
```

Comment: Why does every single answer on StackOverflow that uses LINQ-to-XML involve `.Descendants`? Why recursively search the whole document for the elements when they're known to be the children of the root element? Just wondering...

Comment: @dtb: That's a fair criticism - it's easier/shorter to prototype and makes less assumptions about your xml structure but for large xml documents it would make a difference

Answer (score -1):

If you have no control of the format, and it's likely to change in the future, I'd consider [using XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) as well, so you can modify your selects with fewer code-changes.  For example, the XPath to get System ID would be:

```
//MessageContent/MessageDetails[Name='System_Name']/Value
```